# Metamask "Unknown props error"?

Tags: testrpc, metamask

I am using Metamask on Chrome. While I was clicking to send ETH on Private Network (localhost: 8545), I have been getting an error about "**Unknown props `network`, `identities`, `addressBook` on  tag. Remove these props from the element.**" in Chrome Console screen. It is ok for connection and ETH balance.

Do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking at the MetaMask UI console. This is a react warning about some properties that are being passed to a component. It shouldn't affect your usage of MetaMask at all.